# Implementing required method in all inherited classes, with parameters depending on inherited type

Tags: c#, .net, oop, polymorphism

Let's say we have several different classes: `RecordTypeA`, `RecordTypeB` and `RecordTypeC`. They each need to implement a method `bool isMatch()`, which will take an instance of an object of the exact same type, and return whether or not they are the same, based on their attributes. So,

```
class RecordTypeA
{
    public string field1;
    public string field2;

    public bool isMatch(RecordTypeA other)
    {
         if ((this.field1.Equals(other.field1)) && (this.field2.Equals(other.field2)) )
         {
              return true;
         }

         return false;
    }
}
```

and similarly for the others.

They are all share some of the same parameters (like `field1`, and `field2`). So, the first thought that came to mind was to use inheritance, and then just define the `isMatch()` for every single one of them. However, I don't want to rewrite this code for every one of them, as the only thing that would be different is the inherited type.

I tried inheriting from a `Record` class, but that had all derived classes taking a `Record` as the parameter for their `isMatch()` methods. I don't want somebody passing a `RecordTypeB` into the `isMatch()` method of a `RecordTypeA` object, for example.

In other words, how to go about ensuring all of these types have a method `bool isMatch()`, taking another object of its same type? That is, `RecordTypeB` must implement `isMatch(RecordTypeB record)`.

I feel like I am either overthinking this, missing something, or both.

Edit: based on a comment, using generics:

```
public interface IRecord<T>
{
    bool isMatch(T record);
}

public class RecordTypeA : IRecord<RecordTypeA>
{
    public bool isMatch(RecordTypeA record)
    {
       // do the comparison
    }
}
```

Comment: From your description, it sounds like the method or, more likely, the entire containing class, should be generic. See marked duplicate. Just make the method parameter's type the generic type parameter.

Comment: I had a feeling generics might be the way to go, but didn't have a good think about it before I posted it.

Comment: Would using an interface be a good idea? I will add an example to the post above.

Comment: Interface might or might not be useful, depending on the exact use case. Some people will argue that you should _always_ define your public API in terms of an interface. Others will say that there's no point, if you have a common base implementation that always must exist. The question of whether to define an interface or not is orthogonal to the question here. You can declare generic types or methods with or without declaring them within an interface.

Comment: The reason interfaces came to my mind was that they are like a "contract", for classes to implement certain methods. Combined with generics, I created something like the code I just edited into the post, which is probably not the best solution. In any case, I think I am overthinking this. I could just go ahead and write out the method for each class, as it's only a couple lines.

Comment: _"they are like a "contract""_ -- not really "like a contract" so much as they _are_ a contract. That is the conceptual basis of the interface type. From a programming basis, there's not much practical difference between using a base type or an interface. Indeed, the .NET runtime manifests interfaces as, essentially, an abstract class without any implementation. If you want to use a base class but require this particular method to be implemented, you can make the method abstract, and provide the other base features in the base class.